# Two good things put together create a bad thing

Tags: nouns

I had this word as a vocabulary word in jr high I think.  The definition is things that are good individually but bad when put together.  I cannot think of the word!  The example was ketchup and ice cream.  Good individually, disgusting together.  Help!  And thanks!

Comment: _Mismatches_, maybe?

Comment: *Anti-synergistic*?

Comment: *A match made in hell*?

Comment: _Repugnance_? [OED gives the sense of "disagreement in feelings and tastes" but it usually connotes strong disgust in the current vernacular.]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of:

***incongruous***<sup>1</sup>:

> lacking in harmony or compatibility or appropriateness;

***inharmonious***<sup>2</sup>:

> 1. not harmonious; discordant.
> 2. not congenial or compatible; disagreeable.

***incompatible***<sup>3</sup>:

> 1a. Not capable of existing in agreement or harmony with something else

***clashing***<sup>4</sup>:

> 3. An incongruity or unpleasant juxtaposition of different colors or elements.

---

<sup>Definitions from the The Free Dictionary.</sup>
<sup>1</sup><sub><sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incongruous</sup></sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub><sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inharmonious</sup></sub>  
<sup>3</sup><sub><sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incompatible</sup></sub>
<sup>4</sup><sub><sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clashing</sup></sub>

Comment: I think 'discordant' is the best on offer here.

Answer (score -1):

**Antagonistic** refers to two things that work in opposition. This doesn't relate to their quality individually, however.

Comment: Unfortunately, good as they are, none of these terms encapsulates the idea that both elements are good by themselves. I think that would call for an idiom, but I can't think of one in AmE.  Even "a marriage made in hell" carries the suspicion that one (if not both) of the parties to such a combo are bad.

Answer (score -1):

debilitating is one such word to use when each has the 'weakening' effect on the other.

*Update* to add 'source' - just type in Google and it auto-outputs following info

debilitate

verb

make (someone) very weak and infirm.

Comment: Can you add detail and a (link to a) definition to substantiate this?